# Is 85°C on the CPU and GPU a high temp for new laptop?

Tags: overheating, computer-behavior

Something unusually is happening to my 5 days old ASUS K556UQ-DMOO2D laptop

Specs are:

- INTEL CORE 17-6500U 2.5GHZ - 3.1GHZ
- RAM 8GB DDR4
- GT 940MX 2GB

I can play other AAA games like *Counter - Strike Global Offensive*, Overwatch and Black Ops at ~65-72°C but when I play *League of Legends*  temperature goes “crazy” to 85°C.

I did a research on Internet and i found out that for PC this is considered a normal temperature but I dont know if this is a normal temperature for laptops.

Beside that I dont why temps goes “crazy” only at *League of Legends*. If anyone has any idea, please share it.

Comment: Are we talking about GPU temperature?

Comment: My experience has been that laptops generally run a few degrees warmer than desktops; this is likely because laptop CPUs can't have as large a heatsink associated with them, and laptop computers in general don't have as good airflow as is possible with desktops.

Comment: Ow sorry forgot to add it!

Comment: As a frequent user of a gaming laptop I can confirm from personal experience that such temperatures are nothing to worry about given the power/cooling ratio in high performance laptops. I combat high temperatures by improving airflow with a pad [such as this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TeckNet-Laptop-Notebook-Cooling-Cooler/dp/B00Y1CNDES/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1495465187&sr=8-2&keywords=laptop+cooling+pad). Note that games that are better optimised to use multiple CPU threads tend to run hotter, as the CPU consequently works harder in these games - maybe League of Legends is one such game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) the max temp is 100 C.  This doesn't mean you should run your CPU at or near this temperature.  Indeed, I would be wary of running any processor at over 70 C for an extended period of time.

As mentioned above, there are possibly a number of things going on.  One is there is limited airflow within laptops.  Another is that oftentimes, laptops share the heatsink between the CPU and GPU.  This means that laptops will usually run a little bit hotter than desktops.

To reduce your temps, verify your fan is set to 'performance' mode, or always on.  Clean out the vents/heatsink fins.  Don't leave your laptop on insulating material (e.g. on your bed or coach).  Use a cooling pad underneath.  Check that the CPU is set to dynamically change the operating frequency.

Comment: Its new laptop, so i dont need to clean the fan for the moment. Opening it would avoid my warranty maybe.

Comment: Dont take it wrong. I like your idea but the last paragraph doesnt fit with my question at all i think.

Comment: @TheToxicDream your question is about a high temperature on your laptop, with a sub question about why *League of Legends* causes this high temperature.  The last paragraph is good advice on how to manage temperature better.  That is very related to the main question..

Comment: @CheesusCrust sorry i think i misjudged him.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, there's a few things to consider when comparing a laptop to a desktop.

1. Case Size (Airflow)

Laptops are naturally compact, whereas a desktop has a lot more breathing room. Laptops, especially recent models, tend to have everything soldered to the motherboard as well, in an effort to save even more space. Every nano-meter counts nowadays. Because of this, laptops won't have as much airflow in the case, nor will they have larger heatsinks, as Jeff Zeitlin mentioned.

2. Fans (Airflow)

My desktop keeps itself at a cool ~35°C while idling, and this is partly due to fan configurations. Two intake fans and one exhaust fan keep cooler air moving in, while pushing out hot air from the back. The more fans, the better. In the case of a laptop, typically only the CPU and, depending on the card, the GPU, have fans. There is no room for a proper intake and exhaust set up, so things will generally be hotter.

3. Specifics to your situation

Black Ops (depending on the version) and Overwatch are not what I would consider graphically intense games. They can be, but with the settings turned down a bit to favor performance, your laptop probably won't generate much heat. I can't say as much for League having never played it, but I imagine you've got some settings turned up higher on it, which can lead to a higher heat graphics card.

85°C isn't good by any means, but it isn't necessarily bad. You would do well to worry once you start hitting 90°C, as you're getting closer to temperatures that can damage your card and internal components.

Perhaps try taking the case off of your laptop and cleaning it out with some compressed air to get rid of dust. Dust is an excellent heat conductor, and unfortunately finds ways to worm into our electronics.

Comment: I dont know if you read my post carefully but i said it's a new laptop 5 days old so cleaning is not an option for me. You may think that the laptop might have been on the shop for 1 month but i asked the retailer and he just got it delivered on Monday so nothing to worry about cleaning for the moment.

Comment: @TheToxicDream Nowhere in your OP did you mention that it's 5 days old.

Comment: I am sorry i will update right now. But i had specify that it was a new laptop but as i see it wasnt enougth information.

Comment: Comparing League to Overwatch and BlackOps, you must know that League requires *less power* than a FPS game.